# The Heisenberg group over $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

This is inspired by a problem from from Dummit and Foote. It asked me to calculate the order of every element in the Heisenberg group over $\mathbb{Z}_2 = \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, which is defined as $H(\mathbb{Z}_2) = \{ {\scriptscriptstyle \begin{pmatrix} 1 & a & b \\ 0 & 1 & c \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}}\ |  ~ a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}_2 \}$.

Plug-n-chug gave

$${\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}^2 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}^2 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} }\ $$

and

$${I = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}^2 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}^2 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}^2 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}^2 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}^2  }\ \ $$

This seems to show that $H(\mathbb{Z}_2)$ is isomorphic to $D_8 =  \lt r, s ~ | ~ r^4 = s^2 = e \gt$.

> > **Question**: Does that mean these matrices give a representation of $D_8$ and, if so, which one? (Like, how would it break down into irreducible reps?) Is this a modular rep since I’m working mod $p$ with $p = 2$?

Comment: Interesting property. This is the nice thing about Foote&Dummit, many examples. Its a shame I never finished it...

Comment: Yes it's a modular representation. The three irreducible constituents are all trivial. (The trivial representation is the only irreducible representation of any finite $p$-group over a field of characteristic $p$.) But note that modular representations do not decompose as direct sums in general (since Maschke's Theorem does not hold).

Comment: Thanks @Derek. If you'll expand on this in an answer (or just toss some reading material my way), I'll be glad to accept it.